# Copy a certificate file to another location

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I have a .crl file which I want to copy to another location. From all the posts which I have seen till now, it can't be done without copying the contents. Is there any method in which I can transfer the file to another location in cpp without copying the contents?

I tried by copying the contents by using the usual fopen method. But the data was not being written to the buffer . If there is no direct method, could anyone please tell me how to read the certificate file and write the contents to another file in a different location?

I have also tried the fstream methods

```
std::ofstream dest("destination.crl", std::ios::trunc|std::ios::binary);

if(!dest.good())     
{         std::cerr << "error opening output file\n";      
          //std::exit(2);    
}    
std::fstream src("sourcec.crl", std::ios::binary); 
if(!src.good())     
{         std::cerr << "error opening input file\n"; 
          //std::exit(1);    
}
dest << src.rdbuf();   
if(!src.eof())           std::cerr << "reading from file failed\n";     
if(!dest.good())         std::cerr << "writing to file failed\n";
```

But it displayed the errors: 
error opening input file 
reading from file failed
writing to file failed

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there any other way than copying the content? Why symbolic link or file shortcut would not work?

Comment: `cp sourcec.crl destination.crl`

Comment: Or do you want some function to copy the file by single function call?

Comment: @kninnug One would assume that the OP wants to do it programmatically, not using system commands.

Comment: @JBentley True, but just in case...

Comment: @dbasic: Yes I need a function which would copy the file to the given path on being invoked

Answer (score 0):

I found this [here](http://blog.emptycrate.com/node/264).

See, this might help you. As you do not want to read, I thought you do not want to perform read and write operation yourself.

```
#include <istream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>


using namespace std;


int main()

{

        fstream f("source.crl", fstream::in|fstream::binary);
        f << noskipws;
        istream_iterator<unsigned char> begin(f);
        istream_iterator<unsigned char> end;

        fstream f2("destination.crl",
        fstream::out|fstream::trunc|fstream::binary);
        ostream_iterator<char> begin2(f2);

        copy(begin, end, begin2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response, I write another answer.

For Window, there is function `[CopyFile][1]`. You can use this function to copy the file without reading the content by yourself.

For linux/unix based, I am unable to find the direct equivalent of `CopyFile`.

I believe that this [question](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might help you.